# Unable to contact local DTServiceHub to bless simulator connection

Tags: ios, xcode8

When I run my basic Xcode project in simulator, I got the below issue:-

> Failed to initiate service connection to simulator.
>
> Unable to contact local DTServiceHub to bless simulator connection

Xcode 8.0

OS 10.11.6

SWIFT 3

[image]

Comment: I have this problem with Catalina, did you find any solution??

Comment: I am using `Xcode 11.4` and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 14):

I reset the Simulator by using the "*Reset Content and Settings...*" and quit my Xcode. Then opened my project again and ran, it worked for me. But I don't know why this error occurred.

Answer (score 13):

In Xcode 9 there is 
**Simulator > Hardware > Erase All Content and Settings**

Comment: also in xcode 11. in the simulator menu, there is the option Hardware|Erase All..

Answer (score 10):

I encountered the same error message in Xcode 9.1, but instead of erasing configurations under **Simulator > Hardware**, I pressed the Run button again and my project successfully built & ran.

Comment: In my opinion, it's because the simulator need time to start up

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I upgraded to MacOS Mojave cause dark mode is awesome. The solution wasn't any of the above, but instead a system RESTART did the trick.

Comment: The question wasn't about why you upgraded to Mojave, so why are you telling us? It's kinda OT

Comment: This answer is what I needed. I upgraded to macOS Catalina and this happened.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset the Simulator by using the "Reset Content and Settings..."
2. Target -> build setting -> search debug -> build option -> debug information format -> change debug to DWARF
3. `Cmd+Shift+K`

it's work for me