# Failed to initiate service connection to simulator?

Tags: objective-c, xcode8.2

When i install  AFNetworking pod file for connecting web service. After installation pod then run my program Xcode show message "unable to contact local DTServiceHub to bless simulated connection".
I help this [link for error from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635861/unable-to-contact-local-dtservicehub-to-bless-simulator-connection) but not solve issue.

I used: Xcode 8.2.1, OSX 10.11.6 and Objective-C.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I had a similar issue. I tried all the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10834817/5175709). Eventually I had to a fresh install of my Mac...even reinstalling my Xcode didn't fix it. I had to do it because I somehow managed to mess up my Mac system files. Perhaps you've done the same :D...But first try the different answers of they link I shared...they may work for you....

Comment: Additionally if you have the simulator running on project and then switch to another project or...then always stop the simulator before running the new project. I find that if I don't do that then the I would have this issue and the only solution was to restart my mac

Comment: I have try this link but not solve my problem.I am just restart my MacBook and reset my simulator then fine work.